# xcode 8.3 Could not launch application process launch failed: unspecified

Tags: xcode8, ios10.3

I have new installed Xcode 8.3 with iOS 10.3.

My application ran on iOS as expected and suddenly Xcode fails to run application on device with error:

> Could not launch "My app" process launch failed: unspecified

[image: Screenshot]

It runs on Simulators and on other device mini-pad (10.2)

Answer (score 7):

I also have this problem when run in iOS 10.3.1 with xcode 8.3.2
Restart device, It will work well

Answer (score 2):

I tried plugging out-in the cable of iOS - doesn't help

I restarted iOS device and Xcode - everything works as expected

*(hope it will help to someone)*

Answer (score 1):

- Plugged out the device cable.
- delete App.
- restart device.
- Delete Xcode Derive Data
- Quit and launch Xcode again.

Build and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Tried below steps :

1. Quit Xcode `(cmd + Q)`
2. Clean project `(cmd + shift +k)`
3. Delete Derived data `(cmd + comma)`

But these didn’t worked. Instead **restarting device worked**!